# Evaluating integrals using dyadic pavings

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

In my multivariable course, we have been working through defining the integral on functions from $\mathbb{R}^n$ to $\mathbb{R}$ using dyadic pavings, and going through increasingly strong theorems of integrability. Conceptually, I understand what's happening when we construct a dyadic paving over some domain of integration. However, I'm struggling to actually integrate from the definition/apply this notion to proofs.

In particular, our definition of integration involves the limits of upper and lower sums as the paving level approaches infinity.  More specifically, we define the upper sums under the limit by:
$$\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty} U_N(f) = \lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\sum_{C\in\mathcal{D}_N(\mathbb{R}^n)} \textrm{sup}_C(f) \textrm{vol}_n(C)$$
and likewise with $\textrm{inf}_C(f)$ for the lower sum. If these two limits converge to a common value, namely $L_N(f) = U_N(f)$ as $N\rightarrow\infty$, then a bounded $f$ with bounded support is integrable.

My confusion starts when evaluating these limits. Perhaps this is more trivial than I'm thinking, but how do I know what to sum up to? Is that the number of cubes? In that case, would the number of cubes I'm evaluating the sum over be some multiple of $2^N$?